# Looping though Object inside object in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I got the JSON result as attached. It is an object with objects inside. I converted the main object in an array, and now I can loop though it without any problems. However, I can't get the info inside the internal object. By the way, inside the object I can get any number of sub objects, going from 0 to undefined.

I need to use this in a Vue project. But since this is plain JS, I made a file just for testing purposes. If it works in JS, I can make it work in Vue.

I tried to convert the object in an array (which works, and is included in the code), but I can't loop and convert again.

```
let dados = {
  et1: {
      at:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
      st:"Done",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"10000",
    sub1:{
      at:"Integer ligula purus, convallis convallis",
      st:"Done",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"8000" 
    },
    sub2:{
      at:"Mauris felis tellus, ullamcorper eu",
      st:"Done",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"2000" 
    }
  },
  et2: {
      at:"Nunc in urna ultricies sapien",
      st:"Post",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"40000"
  },
  et3: {
      at:"Phasellus varius rhoncus urna, nec",
      st:"Execution",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"4000",
    sub1:{
      at:"Phasellus varius rhoncus urna, nec",
      st:"Execution",
      di:"01/19",
      df:"03/19",
      vl:"2000" 
    }
  }
}

console.log(dados)

Object.entries(dados).forEach(([key, value]) => {
 console.log(value);

 let fields = Object.values(value);
 console.log(fields)
});
```

With this code I got an array, but with the internal objects untouched, as expected. I just need to find how to convert the internal objects. Maybe with an loop inside a loop (I believe this is a bad practice, no?)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: *"Maybe with an loop inside a loop"* : Yes. *"I believe this is a bad practice, no?"* : No

Comment: @Soviut there is code, at the bottom of the snippet

Comment: Or you can try recursion, depends on the use case. If it's only 2 levels deep then just use 2 `for` statements

Comment: What is the expected output? You might have to do `Object.entries(value)` inside the `forEach` depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to loop through each of the top level properties in `dados` and get the values of all the properties of the child objects (`sub1`, `sub2`).

```
Object.keys(dados).forEach(key => {
    let val = dados[key];
    if(typeof val === 'object'){
        Object.keys(val).forEach(k => console.log('%s: %s', k, val[k]);
    } else {
        // do something with non-object properties
    }
});
```

And just to be clear it's not necessarily a bad practice to use loops inside loops. In fact, that's just what the doctor ordered in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For objects of arbitrary depth, you can make a recursive function. It prints regular values and passes objects back to the function. This will print all the values in a depth-first order.

```js
let dados = {et1: {at:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",st:"Done",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"10000",sub1:{at:"Integer ligula purus, convallis convallis",st:"Done",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"8000" },sub2:{at:"Mauris felis tellus, ullamcorper eu",st:"Done",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"2000" }},et2: {at:"Nunc in urna ultricies sapien",st:"Post",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"40000"},et3: {at:"Phasellus varius rhoncus urna, nec",st:"Execution",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"4000",sub1:{at:"Phasellus varius rhoncus urna, nec",st:"Execution",di:"01/19",df:"03/19",vl:"2000" }}}
  
function printValues(obj){
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (typeof value == 'object' && value !== null)  printValues(value) // it's an object
        else  console.log(key, ":", value);
       });
}
  
printValues(dados)
```

You should be able to modify the basic idea to make a flattened array if that's what you want.

Comment: hmmm, maybe I expressed myself badly. The ideal scenario for me would be to get one array for each object (et1, et2, et3) with the sub objects as an array inside. I'm messing with the ideas shown, but nothing to write home about yet. If I can found the answer, I will post it here :)

Comment: @Mvotre it’s helpful in questions like this to post your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say what format you need the data in but i think this illustrates how to get the values from at object at any level. I added the path / level variables to help illustrate what's going on, but you could (for example) use this to flatten the object into a single level (i.e { et1.sub1.st : 'Done' } etc)

```
var values = [],
    path = [],
    level = 0,
    recurse = ob => {
        Object.entries(ob).forEach( ([k,v]) => {
            if(typeof v === 'object'){
                level++;
                path.push(k);
                recurse(v);
            } else {
                path.push(k);
                console.log(`level:${level}, key:${k}, path:${path.join('.')} value:${v}`);
                path.pop();
            }
        });
        level--;
        path.pop();
    };
recurse(dados);

// output (for ex): level:2, key:st, path:et1.sub1.st value:Done etc...
```

Seems worth pointing out that this assumes that none of the values in your object will be arrays. If that's a possible scenario you need to add a check for it.

Comment: Woops - people sure reply quickly on here! I think the earlier answer covers it - I should have refreshed the page before i posted!